# How to use the Social Share cordova plugin in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to share an image which has a URL like `file:///storage/emulated/0/TheFolder/thefile.ext`. When ever i run the operation the file URL is shared instead of the file itself. Please what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/

get base64 image of the image by above documentation

then you can pass the base64 to the share url

Comment: I did what you said but its output was still text. and it looked something like `data:image/*,charset=utf8;base64,/9j.......`

Comment: Ok i will provide a example

Comment: Wow, Thanks for your help!

Comment: I figured out my mistake. I wasn't using the function the right way.. Instead of `share(message, subject, file, url)`, i was using `share(file)`. Thanks for your help!